# Max length of 12mm OD steel rod for CNC axis

Tags: steel, cnc, bending

Standard rod used for CNC guides, outer diameter: 12mm.
Material: Ck55 steel, hardened to 60 HRC (according to store)

What would be the maximum length I can have before the rod starts to bend?

The guide will only need to hold about 2kg (a cordless router).

Comment: what are the loading conditions? are you loading it as a cantilever or simply supported, or as a column?

Comment: router will be sitting on another rod, supported by linear bearings mounted on these two (hopefully long) rods

Comment: A hardness of HRC 60 would be very unusual for inventory ; it implies a specialized industrial supply. The hardness would corresponds to a yield/tensile ( they would be close) of about 300,000 psi. A hand tool like a wrench would be be roughly half of that , like HRC 30.

Comment: @blacksmith37 OP is referring to stock made specifically for linear rails. That is standard hardness for guide rails. https://www.mcmaster.com/linear-motion-shafts/linear-motion-shafts-5/

Comment: Hi, technically a rod bends for all weights. Its just a question of how much of deflection you can tolerate.

Comment: Yes and no; rails a new thing for me. The data sheet reports HRC 60 surface only and implies HRC 20 in the core . So a very hard wear surface with a tough core , should work. Solid HRC 60 is brittle and would not work well as a cantilever.

Comment: @Alex The hardness doesn’t impact the amount of bend assuming you’re in the elastic range.

Comment: Conventional steels will elastically strain to about 0.3 % ; high strength steels will elastically strain to about 0.6 %.

Comment: You need to improve your specification:  how much deflection and under what load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a cantilever beam with a concentrated load at the end like the following:

[image]

In that case, the beam will start to bend for any length L ; for small Ls it will be imperceptible.

In any case, the maximum deflection will be:

$$\delta_{max} = \frac{P\cdot L^3}{3 \cdot E\cdot I}$$

where:

- E = Youngs Modulus (200 GPa)
- I = Second Moment of Area $I = \pi \frac{D^4}{64}$
- P = Point Load (~ 20 N)
- L = Length of Cantilever

So, if you know what is the maximum acceptable displacement you can solve for it:

$$L= \sqrt[3]{\frac{3 \cdot E\cdot I\cdot \delta_{max} }{P}}$$

---

for the **simply supported case**
[image]

(which is more likely what you will use):

$$\delta_{max} = \frac{P\cdot L^3}{48 \cdot E\cdot I}$$

and

$$L= \sqrt[3]{\frac{48 \cdot E\cdot I\cdot \delta_{max} }{P}}$$

---

**One final thing** is that the load is not only the weight of the router, but also forces from the cutting process.

Comment: thanks. In my case, I want to find out max length of the supporting triangles you have in your drawing. I made a illustration here  https://www.autodraw.com/share/KD9RBXL74V88 (the blue lines). The length of the connection rod should be less than 1 meter, so there shouldn't be any bend there

Comment: @Alex You are never going to get zero bend. The question is what is negligible.